# AOI boundary linked to an account

Tags: planet

Is it currently possible to download the AOI area associated to a planet account as a shapefile or kml. I think **Open California** follows state boundary but for other accounts with different AOI limits this would help when we are drawing regions near the AOI limit as a bounding box or cutoff. This would specifically help when drawing a smaller region of interest outside the framework of planet explorer (for example: in geojson.io or as a shapefile limit if using QGIS or ArcMap) to be used in the API.

Also I may be wrong on this but the Planet Explorer Beta does not show the AOI limits which was available in the scene explorer. However it allows us to copy the curl code which can then be modified to create a json file with filters. So an easy way might be to include the AOI limit in planet explorer as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to query a user's geographic limits or display them as you could with Scenes Explorer. With the different data types, a single user can have multiple geographic limits so it's not as straight forward now.